# How to make screen 'unsensitive' on incoming calls?

Tags: calls, touchscreen, htc-desire-s

Here's the scenario: what I often find happening is that I receive a call on my Android phone (HTC Desire S), and as I'm rushing to get it out of my pocket I'm accidentally managing to swipe the screen, which rejects or accepts the call, when I didn't want to.

What's the best way to avoid this, given that I want to keep my phone in my pocket? I'd kind of like the screen to remain disabled when a call is being received until I press the power button at which point it becomes sensitive. Is there a way to do this or something which would avoid this accidental accept/reject of calls?

Comment: I just did it again.  I just hung up on someone who was calling me.  AAAAArgh!!! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I solved the issue to my satisfaction was to buy and install the [WidgetLocker Lockscreen](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker&hl=en) app.  This is an awesome little app that basically allows you to replace your lockscreen (and incoming call screen too) with something customized.  I just have one horizontal slider to unlock the screen now, and it has completely eliminated accidental screen unlocks, as well as accidental accepts/rejects for incoming calls!  :-)

I would highly recommend WidgetLocker Lockscreen in any case, because being able to customize the lockscreen is really nice.

Comment: An anonymous user asked this (by doing an invalid edit): *WLL has some bugs. On my LG P500 it sometimes unlocks sceen by its self on incomming calls. If I have some SMS or Missed call nottification, screen unlocks on incomming call.
This problem is the biggest minus of android. Solution is wery easy but android builders didn't take it in consideration. Why? Why unlocker is separate from loncher and is hard to override.*

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't quite answer your question, but I wonder if you could change how you grip or store your phone. For example, I never have this problem with my Droid 1. It lives upright in my pocket, and I'm able to grasp it and pull it out without touching the touchscreen at all, and since it's upright, even if I did grab the screen, I would be touching the top part, which is away from the sliders for me.

My previous phone has a little place for a wrist strap, and I tied a big rubber ring to it which I could then grab with one finger to retrieve from the pocket.

Your phone is different of course, but maybe you can reason your way to some handling procedures that work around the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Buy case or cover for your phone. It will give you opportunity to take phone from your pocket without touching the screen. This isn't perfect solution, but I don't see another solutions.

Also I agree with you that swiping screen while getting phone out from pocket is annoying. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Install Tasker from Google Play, create a scene without any further contents, produce a task to show this scene as overlay, blocking, fullscreen, with exit button, and then a profile to run on state call, incoming performing this task.

More beautiful scenes are possible.